# Namespace and base class not recognized - Why?

Tags: vb.net, intellisense, .net-assembly

So I am working on a project someone gave me.

In the project, there is a main `Namespace`, lets call it "`Program`".
In that namespace are several different classes.

Now I had to derive from a class in Namespace `Devices`.
There was already another class derived from the object `Device`.
So I went ahead, created my class, included it in the `Devices` namespace, derived it from `Device` and did my job.

But not shortly afterwards, I couldnt use any of the base variables, methods and so on. The whole intellisense doesnt work on that class.
And even worse is, that it doesnt seem to be included into the assembly.

How can I get my class being recognized by Intellisense, the assembly and so on? I made a test class which only was like this:

```vb
Namespace Devices
    Class Testcle
        ' ... Nothing
    End Class
End Namespace
```

And it worked perfectly fine. It was included in the assembly, Intellisense worked, etc.

The folder structure looked a bit like this:

```
[Project]
↳ [-] Devices (Folder and Namespace)
    [-] AlreadyExistingClassDerivedFromDevice (Folder)
        ↳ AlreadyExistingClassDerivedFromDevice.vb
    [-] MyClassDerivedFromDevice (Folder)
        ↳ MyClassDerivedFromDevice.vb
↳ [+] Other (Folder)
↳ Testcle.vb
↳ Device.vb
```

Is there anything Im missing? Like is there a hidden setting I have to activate?

---

Edit:
The declarations look a bit like this (but in different files):

Device.vb

```vb
Namespace Devices
    Public MustInherit Class Device
    ' ...
    End Class
End Namespace
```

This works:

AlreadyExistingClassDerivedFromDevice.vb

```vb
Namespace Devices
   Public NotInheritable Class AlreadyExistingClassDerivedFromDevice
        Inherits Device
   ' ...
   End Class
End Namespace
```

This doesnt work:

MyClassDerivedFromDevice.vb

```vb
Namespace Devices
   Public NotInheritable Class MyClassDerivedFromDevice
        Inherits Device
   ' ...
   End Class
End Namespace
```

There is literally no difference with the inheriting classes. Only the inner workings. But those shouldnt have an effect on the accessability of the ctor or Intellisense or something, right?

Comment: Do you have `Public Class Testcle` or just `Class Testcle`?

Comment: It is `Public NotInheritable Class MyClassDerivedFromDevice Inherits Device`

Comment: So, which one is not working? `MyClassDerivedFromDevice.vb` or `Testcle.vb`? Can you post their declaration, including additional/nested namespaces?

Comment: `MyClassDerivedFromDevice.vb` is not working. Yes I'll post them trimmed down to the minimum as soon as possible. Right now I dont have time, unfortunately.

Comment: Since you mentioned folder structure in regards to Namespace ("Devices (Folder and Namespace)"), I suspect you are used to the C# IDE that relates a folder name and Namespace when adding a class to a folder;  VB does not do this. You have to explicitly wrap classes with a NameSpace block.  You can use the "Class View" (View Menu->Other Windows->Class View) to determine where a class is located in the namespace tree.  With your minimized code posting, it is difficult to surmise what the issue is.

Comment: @Jimi I just updated it. I hope this helps a bit (Folder structure update and declaration of classes, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write this as an answer because it solved my problem. However, I dont know what cause it had and dont know the exact steps to actually solve the problem in a 'proper' way.

**What I did is the following:**

I renamed the file `MyClassDerivedFromDevice.vb` to `MyClassDerivedFromDevice_Old.vb`, created a new class named `MyClassDerivedFromDevice.vb` and just after adding the namespace and making sure Intellisense and everything works properly, I just copied the code from `MyClassDerivedFromDevice_Old.vb` (after the line `Namespace Devices` up to `End Namespace` into `MyClassDerivedFromDevice.vb`.

That solved the problem.

---

**Short version:**

1) Rename `NotWorkingClass.vb` to `NotWorkingClass_Old.vb`

2) Add new class with name `NotWorkingClass.vb`.

3) Add Namespaces to `NotWorkingClass.vb`.

4) Check whether everything works accordingly (Intellisense, etc.) and it is recognized by Visual Studio.

5) Copy all code starting after `Namespace X` to right before `End Namespace` from `NotWorkingClass_Old.vb` to `NotWorkingClass.vb` (which should now work).

Comment: It appears that this was just an IntelliSense glitch (which happens often). I was just about to ask you if the compiler complains when you try to access the base class manually (without relying on IntelliSense).

Comment: Yeah maybe I should have tried that but this program is quite big so I would have to build a structure around it before accessing it itself. Should I mark this as accepted answer?